# CALayer frame origin.y is flipped, 0 is at the bottom?

Tags: objective-c, calayer

When I Add a set the fram on a CALayer the origin.y is reversed, 0 is at the bottom of it super layer and increasing origin.y moves it up in its super layer. Is there something I did to cause this to be flipped? I would expect origin.y=0 to be the top, not the bottom.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you on iOS or Mac OS?  It makes a difference.  iOS (0,0) starts from the top left corner of the screen.  Mac OSX (0,0) starts from the bottom left.

Comment: Im in Mac OSX, so I guess it's working as it's supposed to. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can flip the coordinate system to behave like iOS like this...

```
layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: I believe you meant `CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);`

Comment: I have same problem in my MacOS app. This not making any change in my code. I tried it in ViewDdiLoad and ViewWillAprrear too but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

my two cents for UIViewController and swift:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        #if os(iOS)
        let layer = view.layer
        layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, -1.0, 1.0)
        #endif// no need under OSX. in this way we can use ONE parent controller for iOS and OSX ...
}
```