# How to change CALayer frame origin.y from top of the screen

Tags: swift, macos, frame

I have MacOS app and when I am setting frame's origin.y, my View is tarting from bottom. In iOS app origin.y will start from top. How can I change it.

I tried below code([Suggested by Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176737/calayer-frame-origin-y-is-flipped-0-is-at-the-bottom)) in ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear but no luck.

```
self.view.layer?.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, -1.0, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Coordinate systems have different drawing orientations in MacOS and iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Devpedia-CocoaApp-MOSX/CoordinateSystem.html

After you've "flipped" your system by y-coord with `CATransform3DMakeScale`, you have to "shift it back" with `CATransform3DMakeTranslation`.

Smth like:

```
CATransform3D t = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
t = CATransform3DTranslate(0,layerHeight, 0); // or -layerHeight, you should test 
self.view.layer?.sublayerTransform = t;
```

Comment: sorry to ask but what is layerHeight in above example? @Olha

Comment: @LakshmiYadav Probably it's `self.view.layer!.frame.size.height`. In any case, you can play with it and declare `layerHeight=100`, or `layerHeight=500`, and see what is changed

Comment: @Olha this is objective-c code OP ask in Swift as tagged

Comment: I have converted it into swift and used but no change.

Comment: @LakshmiYadav Could you post a link to your project? Or reproduce this issue in a new project and post in on github

Comment: because this one line of code you've posted needs more context

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `isGeometryFlipped` property of `CALayer`, that controls if `y = 0` is at the top or the bottom of the screen.

Comment: when I am printing `layer?.isGeometryFlipped` its nil.

Comment: Then your layer is nil. `NSView` doesn't use a layer by default, you will need to set `wantsLayer` to `true` on the view first.

Answer (score 0):

implement a method `-(BOOL)isFlipped` to override the native coordinate system  in your macOS `NSView` class.

```
- (BOOL)isFlipped {
    return YES;
}
```

This should flipp around all coordinates in the specific view.
According to NSViews/UIViews, `CALayer` will behave different.
But there is also a way to flipp a single CALayer around. Your CALayer should have a property `(BOOL)geometryFlipped` which you can set.

```
CALayer *yourlayer = [CALayer layer];
yourlayer.geometryFlipped = YES;
```

or subclass `CALayer` and implement

```
-(BOOL)contentsAreFlipped {
    return YES;
}
```

With *"Flipp"* is the y-coordinate meant. The x-coordinate should stay as is.